# In what case we should implement Iprincipal and IIdentity

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization, forms-authentication

I knew how to implement form authentication in a traditional web site. But I am confused with these two interfaces. What are they used for and why do we need to implement them?

Answer (score 0):

They are already implemented for you.  HttpContext.User implements IPrincipal and HttpContext.User.Identity  implements IIdentity.

As far as what they do, it depends on the version of .NET you are using, as things have changed a bit.  This is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748503.aspx) for the latest .NET 4.5